# How to create e.ID == id lambda expression dynamically

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, lambda, dynamic-linq

I've read many great answers here on stack about dynamic creation of lambda expression, but cannot make my own.

I need to select entity from DB by `ID`, but I don't know its type beforehand. Only name of a type. So:

```
var modelType = Assembly.Load("Models").GetTypes().First(t => t.Name == type + "Model"); 
MethodInfo method = typeof(CommonRepository).GetMethod("GetByExpression",
                           BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);



var arg = Expression.Constant(null, modelType);
var body = Expression.Convert(Expression.PropertyOrField(arg, "ID"),
    typeof(int));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, bool>>(body);

var model = method.Invoke(this, new object[] { lambda });

var field = modelType.GetProperty("Disable", BindingFlags.Instance);
field.SetValue(model, false);

this.marathonRepository.SaveOrUpdate(model);
```

I guess in my code I've made "`e.ID`" part of lambda. How to make "`== id`" part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to break the expression up into its parts, using comments to help understand the expression to be built.

Consider the following...

```
// id
var id = 2;
var idConstant = Expression.Constant(id);
// (object e) => ...
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
// (object e) => ((modelType)e).ID
var property = Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression.Convert(param, modelType), "ID"));
// (object e) => ((modelType)e).ID == id
var body = Expression.Equal(property, idConstant);

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, bool>>(body, param);
```

Comment: Just declare `param` as `typeof(object)` and add a `Convert(param, modelType)` in the `ID` accessor, and you've nailed it.  OP also had a conversion on `ID` to `int`, which may or may not have been superfluous.

Comment: @MikeStrobel yeah I was initially trying to figure out what their intent was there.

Comment: Fixed the argument type for you to make the lambda representable as `Func<object, bool>` as opposed to `Func<?, bool>` where `?` is not statically known.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped, but i had to use reflection to create Func of right type - modelType.